# How to target the first occurrence of an element in the parent container by using css?

Tags: css

I am trying to target the first occurrence of .discount class but some how its not working. I am trying .discount:first-child but its targeting all the .discount class inside the .container class.

Any one has idea how can I target only the first .discount class element inside the .container element?

My HTML code looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="some-class">
            Product
        </div>
        <div class="some-class">
            Discount
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product">
            Product 1
        </div>
        <div class="discount">
            $1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product">
            Product 2
        </div>
        <div class="discount">
            $5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product">
            Product 4
        </div>
        <div class="discount">
            $10
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

why you dont put another class inside the div you want. like this http://jsfiddle.net/8L0un657/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="product">
        Product 1
    </div>
    <div class="discount selected">
        $1
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`.wrapper:nth-child(2) > .discount:nth-child(2)`

This selects the wrapper class which is the 2nd child of its parent (i.e. container)and then selects the discount class which is the second child of its parent i.e. wrapper div.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hs7tvjac/)

But you can also use 'id' to reference any particular element.